# Connect Linksys WRT54GC to other router via wireless

Tags: wireless-router

Is it possible to connect a Linksys WRT54GC router to another Linksys router via wireless?

I have 2 routers, but don't have a long enough cable to connect them. They both have wireless, therefore my idea was to connect them via wireless, but I could not find out how.

Comment: What is the other linksys router? Which one is hosting the internet connection?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The feature you're looking for is called `Wireless Bridging`. It doesn't look like the WRT54GC supports it, and with the small amount of memory on the device, replacing the firmware with one that would is most likely out of the question.

If the other router supports wireless bridging, or can be flashed with a modded firmware that supports it (such as DD-WRT), then you could use that as a client bridge to connect to the WRT54GC.

Comment: other one is L-WR741N / TL-WR741ND

Comment: it looks that I will need to search for a cable.

Comment: @Dainius It looks like your other router can support wireless bridging, through DD-WRT if not natively. If you can use the WRT54GC as the access point and the TL-WR741ND as the client to connect wired devices to the wireless network, then you can make it work. It might require getting your hands a little dirty with custom firmwares, though. (If you want to try that, and can't figure out how, post another question asking how to configure the TL-WR741ND as a wireless bridge and connect it to an AP)

Comment: ty, I will try. It's not critical therefore I can wait till I find a cable.